# What should I call this kind of animation?

Tags: phrase-requests, vocabulary

On opening [this link](http://tr.smart.com/smart-fortwo-smart-fortwo-cabrio-tasar%C4%B1m/31568682-95a7-5715-99fc-6d0d1bfd7d42) you will see a car that has a kind of glowing bulb on it.

[image: in the animated version, concentric rings of yellow expand outward when moused over - this is a static screenshot of part of the image]

I am talking to my client and we both are not good in English. I have to find this kind of animation from a search engine. I have tried the keyword *glowing bulb* but didn't get my desired results. What do we call this kind of animation; what should I search for? A *glowing bulb* or *glow* or *alert* or what?

Comment: I'm not sure what to call it, but is it the animation technique you want to describe (how it was made), or the way the glowing aspect of it changes (flicker, pulsate, flash)?

Comment: i just want to kno what do we call this kind of effect in english so that i can search in google.

Answer (score 2):

You need to search for ***"animated glowing orbs"*** or ***"animated pulsating orb"*** and append your preferred animation studio software into the search terms.

I am of the opinion that the concentric circles glowing around the orbs shown in your example are more of a preference by the creator.

You might want to check on youtube for tutorials as well.

Answer (score 0):

The glowing bulbs themselves are not animated. Are you referring to what happens on the panels behind the car? That's the only animation I see. The effect that is happening there is called a *cross-dissolve*.

EDIT

Now that you're clearer about what you mean, I would call that effect a "pulsating glow" effect.

Comment: if u let page load you and see carefully those small bulbs for a while u will realize that they are glowing. i want to know what do we call that kind of animation.

Comment: @mysterious the closest I can think of is *pulse*.

Comment: It looks like it's a rollover animation, but I don't know what you call it.  Some kind of highlighting.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to "glowing," "pulsating" or "pulsing" might work.

Note that one might refer to the globes as "orbs." So `glowing orb` might be a good search term. "Pulsating" might bring you some adult-oriented pages you may not really want to see, at least for this project.